# Scale (zoom) whole canvas with kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I'm creating an image editor using canvas and kineticjs. At the end of the process I export the whole canvas to an image.

My issue is that I want to scale down the editor window, i.e. use a 500x500 canvas to export a 1000x1000 image.

What I've done so far is scale down all canvas elements by my scale factor, and then on export setting the stage size to the required size. The problem is that this scales up the image size but not the elements in the canvas.

Any Other ideas on how I can scale down the visible canvas, yet export a full sized image?

Comment: can you show some code for scaling? have you tried stage.setScale(x,y) ?

Comment: yes I have, this will scale the size of the elements in the stage, but not the stage itself, allowing items to be dragged outsite where they should

Comment: well, you can also dynamically resize the stage, like with stage.setWidth() and stage.setHeight()

Comment: nevermind, I re-read your description. Basically, if you could provide some code, that would help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @EliteOctagon Your Idea actually worked. I set both the size and scale based on my scale ratio variable, and when generating the image temporarily set both the scale and the size to full, returning it immediately after the image is generated

Answer (score 1):

After playing around and with some help from @EliteOctagon, here's my solution:

1. set a variable with a scale factor
2. save original size
3. create stage with both  scale (for the inner elements) and a scaled down height/width (for the canvas itself)
4. when saving image, temporarily set height/width to original and scale factor to 1